# Request failed with status 400 due to invalid argument: invalid argument: unrecognized capability: pollTimeout

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io

[error while trying to run basic mocha structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9oxB.png)

printing console log

Comment: Please post the code and error as plain text with correct format instead of screenshots